# Json parsing Python subprocess

Tags: python, json

Here's the code:

```
inputDomain = subprocess.Popen("cat /etc/localdomains", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
domains = inputDomain.stdout.read().splitlines()

for domain in domains:
   cmd = "whmapi1 domainuserdata domain " + domain
   output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   jsonS = json.dumps(output.communicate())
   print json.loads(jsonS)['data']
```

here's there error

root@server [~/testP]# python copie.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copie.py", line 18, in 
    print json.loads(jsonS)['data']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

and this is an example of the json i need to parse:

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "userdata":{ 
      "phpopenbasedirprotect":1,
      "options":"ExecCGI Includes",
     "ip":"10.0.0.1",
     "hascgi":"1",
     "group":"user",
     "usecanonicalname":"Off",
     "scriptalias":[ 
        { 
           "url":"/cgi-bin/",
           "path":"/home/user/public_html/cgi-bin"
        },
        { 
           "url":"/cgi-bin/",
           "path":"/home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/"
        }
     ],
     "user":"user",
     "ifmodulemodsuphpc":{ 
        "group":"user"
     },
     "owner":"root",
     "documentroot":"/home/user/public_html",
     "userdirprotect":"",
     "serveralias":"parkeddomain.com www.parkeddomain.com www.example.com",
     "port":"80",
     "homedir":"/home/user",
     "ifmoduleconcurrentphpc":{ 

     },
     "customlog":[ 
        { 
           "target":"/usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com",
           "format":"combined"
        },
        { 
           "target":"/usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log",
           "format":"\"%{%s}t %I .\\n%{%s}t %O .\""
        }
     ],
     "servername":"example.com",
     "serveradmin":"webmaster@example.com"
  }
}
```

So i need the user and the domaine, but python always answer that i need a int. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: are you sure `jsonS` is not a list? in which case you'd have to do `json.loads(jsonS)[0]['data']`

Comment: and what the hell with `inputDomain = subprocess.Popen("cat /etc/localdomains", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`? python can read text files without the need of calling `cat` !!

Comment: yes i already try this.. it give me the same error...

Comment: You'r right jf i can change that, but that is not the problem for now..

Comment: just `print(type(jsonS))` just to see the type

Comment: it print <type 'tuple'>

Answer (score 10):

I had problems running the above under Python3, so here is a way to achieve what OP is asking in Python3

```
import subprocess
import json


def getProcessOutput(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    data, err = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode is 0:
        return data.decode('utf-8')
    else:
        print("Error:", err)
    return ""


for domain in getProcessOutput("cat /etc/localdomains").splitlines():
    cmd = "whmapi1 domainuserdata domain " + domain
    print(json.loads(getProcessOutput(cmd))['data'])
```

It outputs `Error: None` because my machine doesn't have `/etc/localdomains` but otherwise it seems to work just fine.

Comment: It should be noted that this is awful code. It seemed to work, but it lacks tests, and couples the success and error into a method, in a way I'm not comfortable with. Something like JavaScript style promises would make me a lot happier for this.

Comment: Works for any code, no need for a "data" key in your output of the run CLI command, any command you run can be mapped to the `data, err`. The `data, err = process.communicate()` runs the CLI command, the output then is in `data`, which you then can check as a json object. For example, to get the message content of the chatbot answer from curl, run `print(json.loads(data)['choices'][0]['message']['content'])`. see [How can I open a licensed GPT chat like on https://chat.openai.com/ on my own user if I have an API key that is not from my user?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/677/3022).

Answer (score 7):

since your process returns a `json` string, there's no need to `dump` it to load it again.

```
# stdout, stderr
jsonS,_ = output.communicate()
```

now you have a string, that you can load using `json`

```
d = json.loads(jsonS)
```

now `d['data']` yields the info you want

Aside: as I said:

```
inputDomain = subprocess.Popen("cat /etc/localdomains", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
domains = inputDomain.stdout.read().splitlines()
```

could be replaced by native python:

```
with open("/etc/localdomains") as f: domains = f.read.splitlines()
```

Comment: Hi thanks but i already try tho, this is the error i got when i do this..TypeError: expected string or buffer So its not a string.. its kinda strange

Comment: can you type `jsonS,_ = output.communicate()`, then `print(jsonS)`

Comment: just did     output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    jsonS,_ = output.communicate()
    print json.loads(jsonS) --> 
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: just `print(jsonS)` don't try to loads.

Comment: ican print it i see the value its like a tuple

Comment: `sonS,_ = output.communicate()`: note the `,_`. Else you get a tuple

Comment: is it possible to parse a tuple into json

Comment: yes, but it will be the tuple for output + error. You're mixing up "tuple in a string" and actual "tuple" object.

Comment: But when I use `shell=True`, the output contains also the shell's prompt on the first line so it breaks the JSON. How to avoid it? In this case, the output would be `$ cat /etc/localdomains\n{ "json": ... }`.

Comment: strange. Anyway, try without `shell=True` as it is often useless when the command is properly written

Comment: also in python 3, to get a string from `subprocess` you need to decode: `inputDomain.stdout.decode()`

Comment: OK, got it. It contains the prompt only when run on a Windows machine, on a Linux one, the output contains only the output of the command being executed. Do you know how to make it work also on Windows systems, please?

Comment: I need `shell=True` because I want to run it without an extension, i.e. `subprocess.run(['cm'], shell=True)`. Then I have two shell scripts, `cm` for Linux and MacOS and `cm.cmd` on Windows. With `shell=True`, the Python script works on both systems.

Comment: `cm.cmd` would need `shell=True` as well or `cmd /c` prefix. oooh I think I'm getting it. Your `cm.cmd` should start by `@echo off` or you'll get some traces.

Answer (score 1):

[`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns a tuple: `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`. when you `loads()` it back you get a list, and then trying to index it with `'data'` will fail. Example:

```
import json
import subprocess

cmd = "/bin/date"
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
jsonS = json.dumps(output.communicate())
print jsonS # ["Fri Feb 10 14:33:42 GMT 2017\n", null]
print json.loads(jsonS)['data'] # TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

It might be enough to do

```
jsonS = output.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: it give me back ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Ok. Stick a print on the `jsonS` to see whether the data actually is a JSON.

Comment: it says that jsonS is a tuple

Comment: I meant, after you make the change Jean and I suggested, to take the first element of the return value of `communicate()`.

Comment: `'data' = output.communicate()[0]`

Comment: True, `process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
process.communicate()[0]['data']` returns the needed "data" key, tested. Therefore, the `json.loads()` is not needed, you can shorten this, as you say at the end.