# How to use the output of a curl command like a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, curl

When I execute the command:

```
 curl http://cs-service:5000/swdpconfig/swdp_templateConfigData/robot_framework
```

the output is:

```
{
  "adm_ts_path": "/data/ngxp_test_automation/bin/admin",
  "be_ts_path": "/data/ngxp_test_automation/bin/backend",
  "fe_ts_path": "/data/ngxp_test_automation/bin/frontend",
  "ip": "40.124.25.232",
  "password": "Er1c550n@123",
  "port": "22",
  "user": "ngxpcdd"
}
```

Now I want to use the key-value pairs as parameters in my python script. How can I do that?

Comment: `a_dict = json.loads(a_string)` ... maybe (probably)

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe it directly to python if you want it executed in cli, and if not as someone mentioned you can save it as a file and load it in python with json.loads

Here is already answered stackoverflow question that might peak your interest

[Pipe output from shell command to a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109859/pipe-output-from-shell-command-to-a-python-script/11109920)

Comment: that the main question **how to pipe it directly to python?**.

Comment: @VishalSingh with a [bash pipe and python script reading stdin ] [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109859/pipe-output-from-shell-command-to-a-python-script/11109920] also edited the main answer for visibility

Answer (score 0):

why would you mix python and curl ... that basically doesnt make much sense ... but you easily can

```
import subprocess,json
data = json.loads(subprocess.check_output('curl ...'))
```

it would be a much better idea to just use python (either `requests` or `urllib`)

```
import requests
url = "http://cs-service:5000/swdpconfig/swdp_templateConfigData/robot_framework"
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

if you wanted to use urllib instead i think its just

```
import urllib.request, json
data = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(urlData).read())
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? With this answer, I found the keywords to search for. I tested the first two code lines and I did not get it to work, but that was for sure my own fault. This answer still helped me clearly to get further: run the comman of the CLI from within Python, that is how it should be done, not by making the output of the CLI and then trying to pass that to Python.

Answer (score 0):

After the hint of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684371/11154841), I got it done with `subprocess.Popen()`, see the code at GenAI [How can I open a licensed GPT chat like on https://chat.openai.com/ on my own user if I have an API key that is not from my user?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/677/3022), search for the heading: "Run the curl string in the CLI and get its output in Python" at the end:

> ##### Run the curl string in the CLI and get its output in Python
>
> With this string at hand, you can run curl in the CLI and still get
> its output in Python, taken from [Json parsing Python
> subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303518/11154841):
>
> ```py
> import subprocess 
> import json
>
> def getProcessOutput(cmd):
>     process = subprocess.Popen(
>         cmd,
>         shell=True,
>         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>     process.wait()
>     data, err = process.communicate()
>     if process.returncode is 0:
>         return data.decode('utf-8')
>     else:
>         print("Error:", err)
>     return ""
>
> # for domain in getProcessOutput("cat /etc/localdomains").splitlines():
> cmd = str_curl
> data = getProcessOutput(cmd) 
> json.loads(data)
> ```
>
> Out:
>
> ```bash
> {'id': 'chatcmpl-abc123......................', 
> 'object': 'chat.completion',  'created': 1706123456,  'model':
> 'gpt-4-0613',  'choices': [{'index': 0,    'message': {'role':
> 'assistant',
>     'content': '"arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:123456789012:model-package/mymodelpackage"'},
> 'logprobs': None,    'finish_reason': 'stop'}],  'usage':
> {'prompt_tokens': 32, 'completion_tokens': 24, 'total_tokens': 56}, 
> 'system_fingerprint': None}
> ```
>
> With that done and loaded into a json dictionary, you can check the
> mere answer in the json tree with:
>
> ```py
> print(json.loads(data)['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
> ```
>
> Out:
>
> ```bash
> "arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:123456789012:model-package/mymodelpackage"
> ```

The main clue of `subprocess.Popen()` comes from Stack Overflow [Json parsing Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303518/11154841) and [another answer there that shows that you can shorten it to `process.communicate()[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42161904/11154841).